# Regular expressions parsing a text document

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to parse a text documents with !if and !endif in between. I want to have the text without !if, !endif and text between them.

For example:

```
text
!if
text1
!endif
text2
```

I would like to have my output = text+text2+..

I tried something like this re.findall(r'((^(!if.*!endif))+', text). But it doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: I don't see how your expression won't raise a `SyntaxError`, as you never don't have a closing apostrophe for your raw text.

Comment: @JoelCornett Its just a typo . I corrected it

Answer (score 4):

Your regex would be:

```
^!if$.*?^!endif$\s+
```

This says:

```
^      - Match the beginning of a line (because of the re.M flag)
!if    - Match !
$      - Match the end of a line (because of the re.M flag)
.*?    - Match any number of characters (non-greedy) (includes line breaks, because of the re.S flag)
^      - Match the beginning of a line (because of the re.M flag)
!endif - Match !endif
$      - Match the end of a line (because of the re.M flag)
\s+    - Match one or more whitespace characters
```

So, you should be able to use it like this, which replaces all occurrences of the above regex with an empty string (nothing):

```
import re
s = "text\n!if\ntext1\n!endif\ntext2"
s = re.sub("^!if$.*?^!endif$\s+", "", s, flags=re.S | re.M)
print s
```

This [will output](http://ideone.com/yBHzi):

```
text 
text2
```

Note that this explicitly requires `!if` and `!endif` be on separate lines. If this isn't a requirement, you can remove the `$` and `^` anchors from the middle of the regex.

```
^!if.*?!endif$\s+
```

Comment: Reading the source of the OP indicated that the text is actually on multiple lines. I edited it accordingly.

Comment: @Karl - I see, thanks for the update. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can help in sed:

```
sed '/^if$/,/^endif$/ d'
```

Here is the algorithm that sed uses:

1. set the variable match=False
2. read next line
3. check if the line is equal 'if'. If so, set the variable match=True
4. if match==True, check whether current-line=='endif'.
   If so, set match=False and delete the current line [and jumps to 0] .
5. print the current line
6. if not EOF , jumps to 1

Comment: I am not quite sure whether a shell script is useful for you.